# Nutch 2.3 and HBase 1.0.0

Tags: hbase, nutch

I try to implement nutch for a projet that will crawl millions urls and actually it seems to work with HBase 0.94 locally.

But the cluster in place is installed with HBase 1.0.0 and we didn't manage to make it works.

Is it actually possible to use nutch 2.3 with HBase 1.0.0 ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: For anyone reaching this old question, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340416/how-to-compile-nutch-2-3-1-with-hbase-1-2-6

Answer (score 2):

HBase0.94 and HBase1.0.0 are not backward compatible. So, if you have code compiled with HBase0.94 then it wont work out of box with HBase1.0.0 cluster. Just recompile your code with HBase1.0.0 and then it should work. You might need to do minor code changes in HBaseClient.

Also, HBase0.94 is not supported by HBase now.

Comment: Do you have more informations about the changes ?
We didn't manage to compile with 1.0.0, i think there is a issue with gora 0.5.

Comment: You can check out release notes. Sorry, i wont be able to summarize them in a comment. Do you have the capability to change code?