# How to compile Nutch 2.3.1 with Hbase 1.2.6

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nutch, gora

I have to setup hadoop stack with Nutch 2.3.1. Supported version of Hbase for hadoop 2.7.4 is 1.2.6 that I have configured and tested successfully. But when I compile Nutch I got following and crawl a sample page I got this error.

```
/usr/local/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/ -crawlId kics
InjectorJob: starting at 2017-09-21 14:20:10
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HBASE_CLIENT_PREFETCH_LIMIT
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionKey.<clinit>(HConnectionKey.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:194)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:115)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
Error running:
```

According to my search such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277364/nutch-2-3-and-hbase-1-0-0) and [this](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nutch-user/201602.mbox/%3C56B2EA23.8080801@cisinlabs.com%3E), Hbase 1.x can be compiled for Nutch 2.3.1. But How to compile I have no idea. Can someone please guide (steps etc.)

Comment: Hbase is started successfully and it has been tested

Comment: are you compile Apache Nutch using ant ?

Comment: I have compiled Nutch successfully and tested but It solrindex plugin is giving some error that I am fixing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Gora 0.7 is the one supporting HBase 1.2.3(+):  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-443

You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837926/582789 where I wrote how to modify Nutch 2.3.1 to work with Apache Gora 0.7. About the patch https://paste.apache.org/jjqz in that answer, use "0.7" where it shows "0.7-SNAPSHOT".

By the way, Apache Gora 0.8 was released yesterday :) Just changing 0.7 for 0.8 should work.

http://gora.apache.org/#20-september-2017-apache-gora-08-release